# Xampp is deleting sessions

Tags: php, xampp

It looks like xampp is deleting sessions when i'm going to another page, does anyone know anything about this? When i'm setting a session and get on another page it is gone.

When i'm staying on the same page the session will stay, but when i move to another page it deletes the session.

Comment: please share some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session handling is PHP specific, xampp knows nothing about sessions.

See [this info](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) for basic session handling/usage.